# Unit test: How to assert multiple calls of same method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a method, which calls another method twice, with different arguments.

```
class A(object):
    def helper(self, arg_one, arg_two):
        """Return something which depends on arguments."""

    def caller(self):
        value_1 = self.helper(foo, bar)  # First call.
        value_2 = self.helper(foo_bar, bar_foo)  # Second call!
```

Using `assert_called_with` helps me asserting just the first call, and not the second one. Even `assert_called_once_with` doesn't seem to be helpful. What am I missing here? Is there any way to test such calls?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`mock_calls`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls) which contains all calls made to a method. This list contains the first call, the second call and all subsequent calls as well. So you can write assertions with `mock_calls[1]` to state something about the second call.

---

For example, if `m = mock.Mock()` and the code does `m.method(123)` then you write:

```
assert m.method.mock_calls == [mock.call(123)]
```

which asserts that the list of calls to `m.method` is exactly one call, namely a call with the argument 123.

Comment: The example in their documentation doesn't make very much sense. Could you show a better example?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I have added an example to my answer above.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Simon Visser's answer, you can use the `unittest.TestCase` `self.assertEqual()` method instead of the `assert` syntax, which I'd say is a better practise in the Unit Test context since you can also add comments to it that will be displayed whenever something goes wrong.

So for example:

```
self.assertEqual(
    [
        mock.call(1, 'ValueA', True)),
        mock.call(2, 'ValueB', False)),
        mock.call(3, 'ValueC', False))
    ],
    mock_cur.execute.mock_calls,
    "The method was not called with the correct arguments."
)
```